# Difference between NMI and AMI scores

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

Can someone explain the difference between two normalized versions of measurements (**NMI** and **AMI**) that measure the agreement of the two assignments, ignoring permutations.

Let consider this code:

```
from sklearn import metrics
labels_true = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
labels_pred = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]

# AMI score: 
score_ami = metrics.adjusted_mutual_info_score(labels_true, labels_pred)  
print(score_ami)

# NMI Score
score_nmi = metrics.normalized_mutual_info_score(labels_true, labels_pred)  
print(score_nmi)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjusted Mutual Information is rescaled such that a random clustering has score 0.

With NMI, even randomly shuffled labels will get a positive score.